# netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__ not implemented for this type

Tags: python, macos, netcdf

I'm stuck with a simple netCDF4 example.

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset

argo_file = Dataset('R20130811_prof.nc', 'r')
n_prof = len(argo_file.dimensions["N_PROF"])
platform_numbers = argo_file.variables["PLATFORM_NUMBER"]

for profile_idx in range(0, n_prof):
    print platform_numbers[profile_idx]
```

I get the following error in running it:

```
$python netcdf4_ex.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netcdf4_ex.py", line 9, in <module>
    print platform_numbers[profile_idx]
  File "netCDF4.pyx", line 2780, in netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__ (netCDF4.c:34558)
  File "netCDF4.pyx", line 2819, in netCDF4.Variable._toma (netCDF4.c:35257)
TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

The code snippet is taken from an existing production code so it cannot be wrong. The issue should be somehow related to my netcdf4 installation.

I'm running on my Mac OsX:

- Python 2.7
- NetCDF 4.3.0

Any hints where to look for a solution?

Comment: the ``_toma`` method converts the underlying array to a numpy masked array (mask represents missing values). Can you please post ``platform_numbers.dtype``, ``platform_numbers.shape``, and ``platform_numbers.getncattr('_FillValue')`` (the value used to represent missing values).

Comment: platform_numbers.dtype: |S1
platform_numbers.shape: (533, 8)
platform_numbers.getncattr('_FillValue'):

Comment: very strange - one letter string as dtype - can you post a link to the netCDF file? Looks like an error in netCDF4.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/knfju2zdgj6ouik/R20130811_prof.nc

Comment: I'm getting the same as you above. If trying with gdal (Python bindings), .ReadAsArray() fails with:
ERROR 1: netCDF scanline fetch failed: NetCDF: Attempt to convert between text & numbers
ERROR 1: NETCDF:"R20130811_prof.nc.nc":PLATFORM_NUMBER, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0
ERROR 1: GetBlockRef failed at X block offset 0, Y block offset 0

ncl_filedump from the command line says the variable is an 8-bit string (as above dtype says) with this content:
1901639 
2901534 
2901530 
1901629 
...

It looks to me there's a mismatch between the declared type and the content.

Comment: the above code works for me - I use netCDF4==1.0.4 and libnetcdf==4.1.1-6 .